# Sublimetext3 jedi autocomplete: Docstrings not showing

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I've just stumbled upon a problem with the jedi autocomplete package in sublimetext3 on windows. I've installed the package via package control and the code completion itself works fine. E.g. when typing "numpy.s" I get the suggestions like "numpy.std".

Unfortunately when this autocompletion popup shows up either by itself or by pressing "ctrl+space" I don't get to see the docstring of the function.
Am I missing some settings here?